# Which IDE can I code in JavaScript(jquery/ajax/json) and compile into winform,web-app,apk?

Tags: web-apps, javascript

I want to code in either C# or JavaScript(with all its libraries), but be able to compile it for use as a winform, web-app, or android apk.

It's not going to be using any devices like cameras or accelerometer so I was thinking using a fairly universal language like JavaScript I should be able to maintain one codebase and compile with resources needed for each platform. But I don't know what all languages have that capability. I am most familiar with Visual Studio winform and asp.net currently.

Which IDE can I code in JavaScript(jquery/ajax/json) or C# and compile into winform,web-app, or apk?

Comment: Do you need it to compiel to all of those or will just one work?